# I do not answer vs I have not answer

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I am about to give a presentation soon. Before I give my speech, can I say: If you have any questions that I ***do*** not answer, feel free to ask me after.

I don't know why my brain keeps telling it's: If you have any questions that I ***have*** not answer, feel free to ask me after.

So, do I use do or have?

Comment: "Questions that I do not answer (in the course of my talk)" or "that I have not answered (by the end of my talk)". Both are possible but, as James says, the second is more usual in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The word "answer" can be both an noun and a verb.

As a verb there is the simple present tense "I answer the question" and its negation  "I do not answer the question".

And there is the present perfect "I have answered the question" and "I have not answered the question"

I this case you probably mean to say "have not answered" since you are talking about the state (at the end of the speech) resulting from the action of not answering a question.

> If at the end of the talk, you have any questions that I have not answered, feel to talk to me.

Answer can also be a noun, as in, "I have an answer". So you could say "If I have not given you an answer to your questions, feel free to ..."